# C# Linq Joining Two Tables Entity Framework Joining Foreign Key Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

In my database, I have the tables.

**Item**:

```
ItemID, Name
```

**Sets**:

```
SetID, Name
```

In the database this would normally be a many to many relationship, so I have a foreign key table in between them called `ItemSets`.

**ItemSets**:

```
ItemID, SetID
```

When I implement Entity Framework, it removes the `ItemSets` table and creates this on both of the classes it auto creates:

**Item**:

```
    public Item()
    {
        this.Sets = new HashSet<Set>();
    }

    public System.Guid ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }
```

**Set:**

```
    public Set()
    {
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public System.Guid SetsID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Now what I'm trying to do is select all of the `Items` that have the same `SetsID` (logically they are part of a set) and return them as an `Item` list.

**Two questions:**

1. Is the table still being represented in this way through the two classes?
2. Is this doable in EF without using custom SQL and only using linq?

Answer like Mithgroth Said

```
db.Items.Where(i => i.SetID == someSetId)
```

My code:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsInSet(Set set)
{
    return IronHelmContext.Items
                          .Where(x => x.Sets == set)
                          .ToList();
}
```

So what it is to note: EF allows this relationship to be determined by just calling the classes of each other. In the `Item` class there is a `.Sets` method (due to custom repository) this allows for the comparison to the `Set` class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can naturally do

```
db.Items.Where(i => i.SetID == someSetId)
```

The data comes from the many-to-many table you declared.

Comment: It focuses on the point i wanted, how is the relationship called and represented in Entity Framework